# How many people does one rabbit feed?

Tags: rabbit

Approximately how many servings of meat can be gotten from one rabbit?  For argument's sake, let's say the rabbit is about 12 weeks old and raised as a foodsource (not hunted wild).  I understand that the answer can vary wildly based on preparation and serving technique- I hope to serve it as a main dish, probably roasted or fried.

Comment: What breed of rabbit?  There are some breeds that grow to 9lbs / 4kg, while others are going to be closer to 4.5lbs / 2kg.

Comment: @Joe - Meat rabbits are generally 3-5 lbs at time of slaughter(12 weeks)

Comment: @Chad : thanks; I didn't realize they were so close in size when they were at that age ... I did find some information saying that the 'meat breeds' are selected for their finer bones (so better meat to bone ratio), but couldn't find specific info on what the ratio actually is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say 3 to 5 people, depending on the heaviness of the sauce, the meatiness of the rabbit etc.

Comment: and the hungriness of the guests ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It not depends only of the rabbit but of the people. 
Think of it like a chicken. You could feed 2 adults and 2 children with one roasted chicken with potatoes. It's the same with rabbit. Add rice or potatoes for those who would eat more than a half roasted chicken.